# Child doesn't terminate correctly in fork

Tags: c++, exec, fork, strcpy

I am writing a c program for a class that is a small shell.  The user inputs a command, and the code executes it using the `exec()` function.

I need to have a fork in the process so all the work is done in the child process.  The only problem is that the child won't terminate properly and execute the command.  When I run the code without the fork, it executes commands perfectly.

The problem seems to be coming from where I am creating the string to be used in the `execv` call. It's the line of code where I call `strcpy`.  If I comment that out, things work fine.  I also tried changing it to `strncat` with the same problem.  I'm clueless as to what's causing this and welcome any help.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

string *tokenize(string line);
void setCommand(string *ary);

string command;
static int argument_length;

int main() {
    string argument;
    cout << "Please enter a unix command:\n";
    getline(cin, argument);
    string *ary = tokenize(argument);

    //begin fork process
    pid_t pID = fork();
    if (pID == 0) { // child
        setCommand(ary);

        char *full_command[argument_length];
        for (int i = 0; i <= argument_length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                full_command[i] = (char *) command.c_str();
                //  cout<<"full_command " <<i << " = "<<full_command[i]<<endl;
            } else if (i == argument_length) {
                full_command[i] = (char *) 0;
            } else {
                full_command[i] = (char *) ary[i].c_str();
            //  cout<<"full_command " <<i << " = "<<full_command[i]<<endl;
            }
        }    

        char* arg1;
        const char *tmpStr=command.c_str();        
        strcpy(arg1, tmpStr);
        execv((const char*) arg1, full_command);
        cout<<"I'm the child"<<endl;
    } else if (pID < 0) { //error
        cout<<"Could not fork"<<endl;
    } else { //Parent
        int childExitStatus;
        pid_t wpID = waitpid(pID, &childExitStatus, WCONTINUED);
        cout<<"wPID = "<< wpID<<endl;
        if(WIFEXITED(childExitStatus))
            cout<<"Completed "<<ary[0]<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"Could not terminate child properly."<<WEXITSTATUS(childExitStatus)<<endl;
    }

    // cout<<"Command = "<<command<<endl;
    return 0;
}

string *tokenize(string line) //splits lines of text into seperate words
{
    int counter = 0;
    string tmp = "";
    istringstream first_ss(line, istringstream::in);
    istringstream second_ss(line, istringstream::in);

    while (first_ss >> tmp) {
        counter++;
    }

    argument_length = counter;
    string *ary = new string[counter];
    int i = 0;
    while (second_ss >> tmp) {
        ary[i] = tmp;
        i++;
    }

    return ary;
}

void setCommand(string *ary) {
    command = "/bin/" + ary[0];

// codeblock paste stops here
```

Comment: I cleaned up your code and still can't make sense of what you are trying to do. I'm guessing that you don't understand much of it either. Seek some help from your instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> Its the line of code where I call
>   strcpy.

You haven't allocated any memory to store your string. The first parameter to strcpy is the destination pointer, and you're using an uninitialized value for that pointer. From the strcpy man page:

> char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);
>
> The stpcpy() and strcpy() functions copy the string s2 to s1 (including
>   the terminating `\0' character).

There may be other issues, but this is the first thing I picked up on.

Comment: I really hate myself now for how simple of a fix that was, but that seems to have been the exact problem.  I changed the definition of arg1 to char arg1[command.length()] and it works perfectly now.  Thanks a ton!